# Jquery upload - MVC file name not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Using Jquery Uploadify, I am not able to pass the file to the controller.

View :

```
       <input type="file" name="file_upload" id="file_upload" />
```

Jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        var uploadUrl = $('#file_upload').data();

        $('#file_upload').uploadify({

            'auto': true,
            'script': uploadUrl,               
            'swf': 'Uploadify/uploadify.swf',
            'uploader': '/ControllerName/Upload',               
            'debug': true

        });
    }); 
</script>
```

Controller

```
  [HttpPost]
    public string Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {          
       //"file" = null is being passed from the view to the controller.
       //code..
    }
```

I am missing something, Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
[HttpPost]
public string Upload(HttpPostedFileBase FileData) {
}
```

or

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload() {
    if (Request.Files.Count > 0 && Request.Files[0].ContentLength > 0) {
        HttpPostedFileBase postedFile = Request.Files[0];
        // Do something with it
    }
}
```

If neither of these are working and your action isn't firing at all (i.e. try debugging and see if a breakpoint within the method is hit), then your issue is most likely the 'script' value - are you running under a virtual directory? If so you'll need to put the name of the directory in front. Uploadify is using an absolute path.

You may also want to check the swf path, `swf': 'Uploadify/uploadify.swf'`. The way it is configured, it is relative to the current page. So if you were on localhost/Somepage it would be looking for /Somepage/Uploadify/uploadify.swf. You can check the browsers Network tab to ensure the uploadify.swf is not a `404`

Comment: Controller is more generally used here.. sorry .. it is a real controller name.. I edited it..

Comment: How is your first option different than what I have?

Comment: Yes it hits the controller .. and I tried passing formdata with another value from the form.. that works well. Problem is with passing the file.

Comment: Can you check that the uploadify.swf is not throwing a 404 on page load? See me response.

Comment: Because uploadify uses `FileData` as the param name passed

Answer (score 2):

Uploadify uses `fileData` by default, so:

```
[HttpPost]
public string Upload(HttpPostedFileBase fileData) 
{
    ...
}
```

but you could also specify this name using the [`fileObjName`](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/fileobjname/) setting:

```
fileObjName: 'foobar'
```

and then:

```
[HttpPost]
public string Upload(HttpPostedFileBase fooBar) 
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not familiar with jquery Uploadify But shouldn't the name of the input match the name of the HttpPostedFileBase parameter? If not then disregard. That's the only thing I see.

```
 <input type="file" name="file_upload" id="file_upload" />

 [HttpPost]
public string Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file_upload)
{          
  ...
}
```

update: I See, Uploadify uses fileData as the parameter.